# Split element with xsl based on length and content

Tags: xslt

I have an XML element with long content, lets say

```
<LongString>Here we have a lengthy string which contains lots of words separated by spaces and it needs to be split</LongString>
```

I want to split it into two elements (lets call them StartString and EndString) according to following rules:

1. StartString will contain as many characters as possible, but at most 40 characters (If LongString has less than 40 characters, then StartString will be equal to LongString and EndString will be empty)
2. If there are spaces withing the first 40 characters of LongString, it will be split at a space
   (If there are no spaces within the first 40 characters, then the split will be after 40 characters anyway)
3. StartString will not end with a space and EndString will not start with a space

So the example above should be transformed into:

```
<StartString>Here we have a lengthy string which</StartString>
<EndString>contains lots of words separated by spaces and it needs to be split</EndString>
```

Whereas

```
<LongString>Just a short string</LongString>
```

will become

```
<StartString>Just a short string</StartString>
<EndString></EndString>
```

and

```
<LongString>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 spaces only at the end</LongString>
```

will become

```
<StartString>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890</StartString>
<EndString>1234567890 spaces only at the end</EndString>
```

How to accomplish this with XSLT?

Comment: Post the code you have so far. Also which XSLT version do you have available?

Comment: I have no code so far, I just started to think about this. I can use whichever version is required. I'm thinking of using tokenize and string-length, but I'm not sure how to put them together (I'm not that experienced with XSL). The other option is to use substring and contains, but as XSL is not really a programming language I'm not sure how the logic described above should be implemented

Comment: Start a xsl introduction, I.e. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or later, if you want to process/analyze text and create nodes, `xsl:analyze-string` can help:

```
  <xsl:template match="LongString">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^(.{{1,39}}$|[^ ]{{40}}|.{{1,39}} )">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <StartString>
          <xsl:value-of select="if (ends-with(., ' ')) then substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1) else ."/>
        </StartString>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <EndString>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>          
        </EndString>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very close to doing everything I want. I will need to do some tweaks, but definitely gets me going to the right direction.

Comment: I took this one step further and defined functions for getting the start and end parts of the string. Now the only question is that if I want to pass the max length of the start (40 in the original example) as parameter to the function, how can I use that parameter inside regex?

Comment: The regex attribute of `xsl:analyze-string` allows attribute value templates (due to that I had to double the curly braces) so you can construct your pattern in there (`regex="^(.{{1,{$length - 1}}}$|[^ ]{{{$length}}}|.{{1,{$length - 1}}} )"` with e.g. `<xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>`) or outside based on a variable and reference it.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I tried to do something like that, but apparently made some mistake 'cause I only got errors. Now it works like a charm.